# How to save updated data only after admin verification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two users: one admin and another simple user. When user wants to edit data, it goes request to admin like "pending for verification"; only after verifying,  data will update. This is image for status column of table:[image]

When data is edited from user, status is 4, and when verified, it must be 5. Can you help me how can I save old data upto when new data is not verified and how to replace it after verification?

Comment: any one is their for help?

Comment: I think you need to create two separate table, 1. store users verified data and another for change data which on pending status,  Once admin is verified then you need to replace users data with change data and change status to verified. You should  store change data in JSON in database

Comment: on edit with simple user u can create another row in your database table with edited data and pending status as temp, after admin accept the edited data, replace this data on with main data and delete this temp data, and if admin refuse it, only delete temp data

Comment: Do you help me by providing code to save temp data and replace it when verified?

Comment: #behzad-dadashpour Do you help me by providing code to save temp data and replace it when verified?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to fix this problem. (Of course, this is my point)

Save the data in a table and add a new column with the status name in this field to check if the data has been verified.

Save the information in a different table. An interface table !!! Then, when the administrator verified that using the Identity Interface, paste these new values, then erase the new values from the interface table after inserting them

Comment: Yes, i understand that but need code for save temp data and replace it when approving in laravel.

Comment: Save the information in a different table. An interface table !!!
Then, when the administrator verified that using the Identity Interface, paste these new values, then erase the new values from the interface table after inserting them.

Comment: need on same table as temp data

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that:

1. Create temp table with foreign key for current table
2. Create temp model
3. User change:

   ```
   $newItem = new TempModel($someRequestData);
   $item->some_foreign_key_name = $request->input('id');
   $item->save();
   ```
4. Admin verify:

   ```
   $newItem = TempModel::where('some_foreign_key_name', $request->input('id'))->first();
   $oldItem = Model::find($request->input('id'));
   $oldItem->fill($newItem->toArray());
   $oldItem->save();
   $newItem->delete();
   ```
5. add $guarded to current model, if you are not using $fillable:

   ```
   protected $guarded = ['some_foreign_key_name'];
   ```